# Laravel5 `RouteServiceProvider` `should be compatible with` Error

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a web application by Laravel5, and in code of Controller, I wrote a code bellow.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    \View::share(compact('post'));
    return view('posts.show');
}
```

but, I want to write as follows.

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    \View::share(compact('post'));
    return view('posts.show');
}
```

and in `RouteServiceProvider.php`, I added `Router $router`

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
```

but, it doesn't work, and I got an error bellow.

> Declaration of
>   App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(App\Providers\Router $router)
>   should be compatible with
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()

What is problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `laravel` version do you use?

In version newer than 5.3, you have to write as follows.

```
public function boot()
{
    //
    parent::boot();
    Route::model('post', \App\Post::class);
}
```

**Reference:**

https://readouble.com/laravel/5.3/en/routing.html

https://readouble.com/laravel/5.2/en/routing.html

`Explicit Binding` section.

Answer (score 1):

`boot` method is inherited from `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` which doesn't have the same signature as yours which is causing this error.

If you have to use the router inside `boot` method then use `app()` helper function to get the instance of the router.

```
public function boot()
{
    $router = app('router'); // Router Instance

    parent::boot();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
As you say, using `app('router')->model('post', 'App\Post');`, it worked perfectly!
`Route::model('post', \App\Post::class);` as well.

Comment: @hiel Yes. Both are different ways of doing the same thing which is "Resolving an instance from laravel's IOC container".

Comment: @hiel `Route::model` is a **Facade** way and `app('router')` is a **Helper** way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like:

Please put `use Route;` instead of use `App\Providers\Router;` and try

Or you can also use the `app('router')->pattern()`.

For more details please follow [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l53-routeserviceprovider-update?page=1).